# TeXnicCenter and svg

Tags: texniccenter, svg

I'm wondering why I can't use the package svg with teXnicCenter. I've seen that one must use shell escape to make it functions. I've also downloaded the latest version of inkscape and of ImageMagick.
So I've written that in my build profile :

```
--shell-escape -synctex=-1 -max-print-line=120 -interaction=nonstopmode "%wm"
```

I've put the shell first beacause I've seen that sometimes it would work better.

Here is my minimal code :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{svg}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\title{Inkscape package on Overleaf }
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htbp]
  \centering
  \includesvg[inkscapelatex=false,width=\linewidth]{test}
  \caption{svg image}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

And I've checked my log file. Here are the parts concerned by escape :

> Package svg Info: Calling Inkscape on input line 9. runsystem(inkscape
>   -z -D  --file="test.svg" --export-pdf="test_svg-raw.pdf" )...executed.
>
> ```
> Package svg Warning: The export with Inkscape failed for file
> (svg)                `test.svg'
> (svg)                Troubleshooting: Please check in the log file how
> (svg)                the invocation of Inkscape took place and try to
> (svg)                execute it yourself in the terminal on input line 9.
>
>
> ! Package svg Error: File `test_svg-raw.pdf' is missing.
>
> See the svg package documentation for explanation.
> Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
>  ...                                              
>
> l.9 ...inkscapelatex=false,width=\linewidth]{test}
>
> Did you run the export with Inkscape? There's no file
> `./svg-inkscape/test_svg-raw.pdf'
> although `test.svg' was found.
>
> [1
> ```

So, I don't really understand what is faulty here. 
Thanks if you can direct me in the right direction to make it work.

Comment: it is likely that inkscape is not an active command e.g. from a cmd line enter `inkscape --version` if you get the response 'inkscape' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file. then it did not install itself on your path so you need to do it manually. If you are not sure which folder it is in and on windows the cmd is> **where /r \ inkscape** If you do get the version shown any where from your system then the --shell-escape did not work for a similar answer see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/474119/170109

Comment: If I understand, the problem is that he can't find it. The fix should be to add the path to the folder of inskcape in the "variable environnement".
I've added the path to the folder inkscape on my "user variables" and on my "system variables" under the variable "Path". To check if it would function, I've tried on the cmd "inskcape -version". I've alose added on miktex the path, by going to preferences>edit>typesetting. He still can't find it. I'm a bit confused now.

Answer (score 0):

There are several steps necessary to meet your achievement

1) enable shell escape, you have done that, otherwise you would be reporting a log error of Package svg Warning: You didn't enable 'shell escape' (or 'write18'), ! Package svg Error: File `test_svg-raw.pdf` is missing.

2) have a valid svg file in a directory you can write a subdirectory to, you don't appear to have that problem otherwise if missing you would see `! Package svg Error: File 'test.svg' is missing.` However if the file was found and produced an invalid result or the subdirectory ./svg-inkscape could not be written in the folder with both tex and svg then the message in that case could be the one you see. Lets presume your test.svg file is valid and you can add a folder below the main tex folder (ensuring that main folder has no spaces or accent's etc.)

3) You must have installed Inkscape on path otherwise you will get the messages you report. so going to a command prompt check by trying> inkscape -version if Inkscape is not on path you should see the following

[image]

You seem to have checked step 3 **so we are left with any issues from step 2** thus you need to recheck if your test.svg or the folders you are running in are questionable.

Comment: By searching on an irrelated subject, I've found that to update packages with MikTex one had to do it as admin.
So I've done that and...Now it's working. Sorry for the lost of time, it was a mere matter of updates.
Thanks for the efforts you've put to help me. I appreciate.