# Error "! Package svg Error: File `placeholder_svg-tex.pdf' is missing."

Tags: pdftex

! Package svg Error: File `placeholder_svg-tex.pdf' is missing.

When I comment out this line: \fig{my_svg}{0.3}{resources/placeholder.svg}

The document compiles correctly.

This is a book template I found online at https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/lix-textbook-class/thyfyzcmmsqc

I tried converting the svg file to a pdf and naming it the name of the file that is missing, and that didn't work. The file is in the correct directory. Any idea how to fix this and what might be causing it?

Edit: I installed TeX Live and am compiling on TeXworks.

Comment: conversion of svg requires inkscape to be installed and use of shell-escape, but it's only an example, you could replace with pdf images rather than svg

Comment: Thank you, @David Carlisle. I installed Inkscape and used steps 1-7 in this answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/474119/189882 and from this page https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/598818/how-can-i-enable-shell-escape I visited the tutorial for TeXworks: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82699/how-to-enable-shell-escape-in-texworks and added the command for shell-escape. Thanks, again!